# get_query_var('paged') return 0 in custom category page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I want to make a pagination for my category page (category is related to custom post type)
But I can't get current page because it returns 0.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
echo get_query_var('paged'); // Output is 0 (Error Here)

$args = array(
    "post_type" => "readings",
    "posts_per_page" => 2,
    "cat" => $term->term_id,
    "paged" => $paged
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

and in functions.php

```
function pagination(){
    global $wp_query;
    $all_pages = $wp_query->posts->max_num_pages;

    $current_page = max(1, $wp_query->posts->query_vars["paged"]);


    if($all_pages > 1){
        return paginate_links(array(
            "base" => get_pagenum_link() . "%_%",
            "format" => "/page/%#%",
            "current" => $current_page,
            "total" => $all_pages,
            "prev_text" => '<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>',
            "next_text" => '<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>',
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: this is extremely similar to the question you asked here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/403410/pagination-in-custom-post-type-archive-php-not-working Is there a reason you're ignoring the main query and creating a brand new query with custom parameters, then working through pagination issues, instead of using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the parameters of the main query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your code can be eliminated by using a `pre_get_posts` filter:

```php
function marco_custom_category_filter( $query ) {
    // only run this on the main query on category archives
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() || ! $query->is_category() ) {
        return;
    }
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    $query->set( 'posts_type', 'readings' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'marco_custom_category_filter' );
```

With this the main query will be customized, and you will no longer need a second replacement custom query that slows down your page and breaks pagination. A standard normal post loop and normal pagination will now work, e.g.

```php
<?php
get_header();

if ( have_posts()
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    the_posts_pagination();
}
get_footer();
```

To customize a category archive, customize the query, do not create a new second query with `WP_Query`

Comment: Thanks for responding, I used `pre_get_posts` but it didn't work. @Tom

Comment: when you say it did not work, what did it do? Please be more specific. Remember that you cannot use this filter unless you change `category.php` back to a normal standard loop, you cannot and should not use a custom loop.

Comment: What do you mean "Normal Loop" , please ?

Comment: A normal, standard loop, the kind present in all default themes and in the codex/devhub, _not_ a custom loop e.g. `if ( have_posts() ) {` not `if ( $query->have_posts() ) {`. Same with the pagination code, use the normal standard functions WordPress provides, not custom functions

Comment: Normal loop can't work because I used custom post type and make it manually

Comment: I used `new WP_Query` and `foreach` loop

Comment: that is a second custom loop, you should not use that, it will create new additional queries that slow down your site, and break pagination. It is not good and not necessary. I have added an example of a normal standard post loop, you need to switch to a normal post loop not a custom/secondary `WP_Query` loop. `WP_Query` is for when you want to make an extra query and show extra posts. A normal post loop is for the main query, the one that WordPress made for you, that loaded `category.php` and read the URL. Use `pre_get_posts` to modify it

Comment: also read this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/

Comment: also this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: Thanks It worked well